# SVN Copy or Merge: Whats best in current situation!

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Check out the following scenario:
/trunk at version: 200
/branches/mybranch at version: 200
/branches/mybranch Last commit version: 192

Now i want the latest code (exact copy) of /trunk to  /branches/mybranch. What is the best option to get the exact copy??
I tried Merge from revision 192-200, but i always missied some files from /trunk. I am not sure which rev. i am missing!!!

How can i get the latest copy exact code???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100% of exact trunk code?
Close (disregard) your current branch and start a new one.

Comment: Did not get you [Close (disregard) your current branch and start a new one.] ????

Yes 100% exact trunk code!

Comment: I agree, start a new branch (e.g. /branches/mybranch2).  The old branch can be left alone for historical viewing or simply deleted.

Comment: `svn copy /<path>/trunk /<path>/branches/branchname`

Comment: getting this error: 'svn' is not recognized as an external or internal command.

Comment: What SVN client are you using?  Do you have TortoiseSVN installed?  If so, you can see this entry in the manual for creating a new branch.  http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html

Answer (score 0):

Just because your branch had its last commit at revision 192 doesn't mean it has all the changes from Trunk since 192.  Look at your logs and see when the last time your branch was merged with Trunk, and merge from that revision to 200.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to replace the branch "mybranch" with the current content from "trunk".

So, just do an svn delete on the branch, and then copy the trunk to mybranch again.

Comment: if i will copy the trunk to mybranch, my branch will considered itself a trunk...

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way is to
-right click /trunk
-tortoisesvn > export to somewhere
-Copy exported files and paste into /branches/mybranch